# Renaming column names with single quote in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with following data;

```
Active_Duration|'Control'|'Test'
    1          | 0.21    | 0.22
```

But I would like the column names without single quotes. I tried following code to treat single quotes as literal, with below mentioned error.

```
 SELECT p.active_duration,
          p.''Control'' AS Control_Rate,
          p.''Test'' AS Test_Rate
   FROM pivot_tab p;
 SQL compilation error: syntax error line 2 at position 16 unexpected ''''. syntax error line 3 at position 16 unexpected ''''.
```

May I know how to rectify it, and rename the column appropriately without single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend you rebuild that table, but if you must keep it, here is are some examples of using columns like these.

```
CREATE OR REPLAE TABLE ugly (
   id number, 
   "'str'" varchar(20), 
   "'str2'" varchar(20));
INSERT INTO ugly values (1, 'hello', 'world');
SELECT * FROM ugly;
SELECT u.$1, u.$2, u.$3 FROM ugly u;
SELECT u.id, u."'str'", u."'str2'" FROM ugly u;
```

I hope this helps...Rich

example of "renaming" a column in your SQL statement:

```
SELECT  p.active_duration,
        p."'Control'" AS Control_Rate,
        p."'Test'" AS Test_Rate
FROM pivot_tab p;
```

Comment: Can also access those columns via $1, $2, $3 etc.

Comment: Apologies if my question was unclear. I am not allowed to rebuild tables, it is result of a subquery. Moreover, my goal is to rename column names so that they show up without single quotes. Hope this clarifies more. Kindly advice.

Comment: I understand about renaming fields and/or rebuilding tables, sometimes you simply can't do it.  In that case, renaming them in your SQL like this should work:
SELECT  p.active_duration,
        p."'Control'" AS Control_Rate,
        p."'Test'" AS Test_Rate
FROM pivot_tab p;

Answer (score 1):

To rename the columns you can use SnowFlake's RENAME syntax

```
ALTER TABLE pivot_tab RENAME COLUMN "'Control'" TO Control;
ALTER TABLE pivot_tab RENAME COLUMN "'Test'" TO Test;
```

Comment: Appreciate your feedback, but for me it is a subquery(CTE).Due to permission issues, I cannot create table. Are there alternatives to redefine column names in Common Table Expressions?Kindly let me know.